# if [-z $var1 ] && [$var2 == "1" ]; then not working as expected

Tags: bash, if-statement, ubuntu-18.04

I'm writing a bash script where i need to combine two conditions with && operator

```
var1=value
var2=1

if [-z $var1 ] && [$var2=="1"]; then
   do something
else
   do something else
fi
```

but it always executes the else part.

**My research**

1. google gave me bash conditions like this but its not working for me.

```
if [condition1] && [condition2]; then
 do something
fi
```

2. Another method i tried is this but it still completely ignored the true part

```
if [[-z $var1 ]] && [$var2=="1"]; then
   do something
else
   do something else
fi
```

3. Tried with -a operator  like this

```
if [-z $var1  -a $var2=="1" ]; then
```

4. tried nested if

```
if [-z $var1 ]; then
    if [$var2=="1"]; then
      do something
    fi
else
      do something else
fi
```

So i know i am doing something wrong but my goal is i want to check for any value in $var1 and also want $var2 condition  to be true and execute the true part.

**UPDATE**

i tried this

```
#! /bin/bash 
set -o nounset
#set -o errexit
set -o pipefail
set -o xtrace
var1=pop
var2=1

if test -z "$var1" && test "$var2" -eq 1; then
    echo Y1
fi

if [ -z "$var1" ] && [ "$var2" -eq 1 ]; then
    echo Y2
fi
```

and this is the output

```
root@c847b6423295:/# ./test.sh 
+ var1=pop
+ var2=1
+ test -z pop
+ '[' -z pop ']'
root@c847b6423295:/#
```

What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: There should be spaces around the `[[` and the arugments `[[ -z $var1 ]]`

Comment: `[-z $var1 ]` should be written as `[ -z "$var1" ]`

Comment: doesnt work with spaces for [ ]

Answer (score 0):

You want to encode "`$var1` is not empty and `$var2` is equal to 1", you can do:

```
if test -z "$var1" && test "$var2" -eq 1; then
    echo Y
fi
```

which is equivalent to:

```
if [ -z "$var1" ] && [ "$var2" -eq 1 ]; then
    echo Y
fi
```

If you want to compare strings, use a single equals sign:

```
if test "aaa" = "aaa"; then
    echo Y
fi
```

Comment: What do you mean there is no equality comparison operator? `[[` supports just fine. `a=foo; [[ $a == "foo" ]]`

Comment: Really? I didn't know! Edited to reflect that. I'm a bit of a posix purist so I have tried to avoid `[[`

Comment: tried the above two methods. Didnt work

Comment: @user1907294 https://rextester.com/KGQSW89546

Comment: @user1907294 Here's a test for both: https://rextester.com/GLN71413